# Well-definedness of tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, universal-property

Given two $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, one possible construction of the tensor product $M\otimes_R N$ is by taking the quotient $F/U$ of the free module $F=\bigoplus_{m,n}R\cdot(m,n)$ and the submodule $U$ of $F$ generated by elements of the form $a(m,n)-(am,n)$ etc. The corresponding bilinear map $\tau\colon M\times N\to M\otimes_R N$ then simply is the projection $(m,n)\mapsto \pi_U(m,n)$.

In order to show that this actually defines a tensor product, one has to prove that the universal property holds: Given a bilinear map $\psi\colon M\times N\to L$, there is a unique linear map $\hat\psi\colon M\otimes_R N\to L$ such that $\hat\psi\circ \tau=\psi$. The uniqueness is obvious because the previous condition leads to $\hat\psi\overline{(m,n)}=\psi(m,n)$, which extends to whole $M\otimes_R N$ by linearity; thus, uniquely determining all of the values of $\hat\psi$. What I am struggling to understand is why this map is also well-defined. There could be two different representations $\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n} \overline{(m,n)}=\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}' \overline{(m,n)}$ of the same element in $M\otimes_R N$, which could get mapped to different values under $\hat\psi$, namely to $\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n} \psi(m,n)$ and $\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}' \psi(m,n)$ in $L$.

How to show that $\hat\psi$ is actually well-defined?

Comment: st.math, you deleted a today's question of yours while I was writing a comment. I just wanted to mention that Bézout's identity also does the job. (After you mark the present comment as read, I shall delete it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**actual answer:**
The key to the well-definedness of $\hat\psi$ is that $\psi : M \times N \to L$ is a $R$-bilinear mapping, so, if we extend it by linearity on $F$, it vanishes on $U$ (it vanishes on each one of its generators because of $R$-bilinearity), so the map $\hat\psi : F/U \to L$ where $\hat\psi(\overline{x}) = \psi(x)$ for any $x \in F/U$ must be well defined, since

$\overline{x} = \overline{y} \implies x-y \in U \implies \hat\psi(\overline{x-y})=0 \implies \hat\psi(\overline{x}) = \hat\psi(\overline{y})$

**previous answer (before edit in the question):**

Simply put, your statement that there could me two different representations $\sum\limits_{m,n}a_{m,n}(m,n)$, $\sum\limits_{m,n}a'_{m,n}(m,n)$ is wrong, since you're not looking at $M \times N$ as a ring or module, you're looking at the set $F$, which is the free $R$-module that has $M \times N$ as a *basis*, they're very different in nature.

So we have that
$\sum\limits_{(m,n) \in M \times N}a_{m,n}(m,n) = \sum\limits_{(m,n) \in M \times N}a'_{m,n}(m,n) \implies \sum\limits_{(m,n) \in M \times N}(a_{m,n}-a'_{m,n})(m,n) = 0$
and from that, since its a basis, we must have that $a_{m,n} - a'_{m,n} = 0 \implies a_{m,n} = a'_{m,n}$ for all $(m,n) \in M \times N$.

Comment: I had a typo in my question. The problem is, given two such sums in $M\otimes_R N$ -- which can actually occur since $\{m\otimes n\}$ is just a generating system of the tensor product and not a basis --, is it true that the map under $\hat\psi$ is equal in the module $L$? I don't think that we're in the free module $F$ in this context.

Comment: I see what you mean. It still doesnt produce any ambiguity, since in this context $M \times N$ isnt an actual algebraic structure, its just the cartesian product, its not equipped with addition of pairs like a direct sum would be, so saying that you could have two different representations for an element in $M \times N$ is still not right

for example, in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, we could for example rewrite (2,5) as $(2+3,1+4)$, that's still the exact same as $(2,5)$, but we cant rewrite it as $(2,1)+(3,4)$, that doesnt make sense in our context, since we're not on $M \oplus N$

Comment: Yes, but I don't think we're in $M\times N$ either. The problem is the following, isn't it? Given $\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n} \overline{(m,n)}=\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}' \overline{(m,n)}$ in $M\otimes_A N$, one has to show that $\hat\psi$ of this gives equal values, i.e. that $\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n} \psi(m,n) = \sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}' \psi(m,n)$, which is both in the module $L$.

Comment: ok, now I see clearly what you're asking, I just made an edit so the answer is more appropriate